# ui-select-no-choice message is displayed if the text length is zero

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, ui-select

I am using ui-select for autocomplete functionality and if there are no results for search criteria then i am using ui-select-no-choice to display  message back to the user.

```js
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="Label">
      Select details
    </label>
    <ui-select ng-model="configItem.details" id="details" multiple class="form-control" theme="bootstrap" title="Choose details" reset-search-input="true" close-on-select="true" spinner-enabled="true" spinner-class="ui-select-spin">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Search.." class="ui-select-match">{{$item.Name}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices class="ui-select-choices" refresh="details($select.search)" refresh-delay="0" minimum-input-length="3" repeat="detail.ID as detail in details| filter: $select.search | limitTo: 100">
        <div ng-bind-html="detail.Name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      </ui-select-choices>
      <ui-select-no-choice>
        No Information found
      </ui-select-no-choice>
    </ui-select>
  </div>
```

```js
 $scope.details = function (search) {
        if (search.length >= 3) {
          AddUpdateService.getAllData(search)
        }
}
```

Since my dataset is huge i used minimum-input-length="4" so there wouldn't be large results but the problem i am facing is if user doesn't enter any data then ui-select-no-choice message is being displayed which is incorrect. I need to display the message if user types more than 4 character.

Here is the screenshot regarding alignment of x icon

[image]

Comment: can you add more code related to html and js

Comment: Edited post with HTML code & backend API call is returning data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of ng-class for hiding that as required.

It is like

```
<ui-select-no-choice ng-class="{ 'hide': $select.search.length < 5 }">
        No Information found
      </ui-select-no-choice>
```

Here is the demo - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/PjuhUR?preview
Hope it helps.

update:: hiding previous results when nothing is typed

```
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter: $select.search" 
ng-class="{ 'hide': $select.search.length < 1 }">
```

Comment: Thanks...that helps. Also i did notice that ui-select remembers previous search results & loads the dropdown if nothing is typed. I don't want that feature. How do i disable that??

Comment: I have updated the answer, just make use of same logic for choices as well

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also another issue, the option to cancel a selected item is not aligned properly(in other words x icon has to be placed either in the center or at the bottom of the selected item). How do we resolve this?? I updated original post with the screenshot

Comment: Can you update code in the demo as well to reproduce the issue ?